# Should I downvote a question I'm voting to close

Tags: discussion, downvotes, vote-to-close

When I vote to close a question, does it make sense to downvote it, too?

My thought is the following:

If I downvote it, less people will possibly see it so it might take longer to have the question finally closed, and I think a question that should be closed should be closed as quickly as possible.

On the other hand, a question that should be closed almost certainly has earned the downvote except it's a not an obvious dupe or good, though off-topic one.

How do you handle this?

Comment: Can't answer, so: Many people downvote for the same reason they voted to close. That's a good indication that the downvote is unmerited. Don't downvote to "punish" the user for asking a question which merits closure - just get it closed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The two actions should be considered separately.

Does the question need closing? If yes, vote to close it. Does it need downvoting? If yes, downvote it.

> On the other hand, a question that should be closed almost certainly has earned the downvote.

Often yes, but not always.

A duplicate can be well written, asked in good faith, but a duplicate. I rarely downvote those unless they're really extreme (like, entering the title in Google gives you a full solution to the problem). An off-topic question can be equally great and well researched - just off topic.

Comment: I was just thinking about those two possibilities and was about to edit my question. Dupes and good off-topic or another se site questions should be handled differently than no code questions asking about where is the syntax error.

Comment: I feel like some questions I ask fall into this category—sometimes I'd say they're of even better quality than the existing question and answer yet mine get downvotes for...being a duplicate?  If a someone writes a beautiful duplicate question, I'd upvote it and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: That's what I usually do too to dupes. @brandaemon